# why we cannot access static members from instance object?

Tags: c#

I know that I cannot call static method from instance object

For example

```
public class A {
  public static int a;
}

A b = new A();
b.a = 5; //which cannot compile
```

I would like to the know the reason behind this.

Answer (score 9):

Because it makes no sense, and leads to misleading code. When reading the code, it gives the *impression* that `a` is part of the *instance* referred to by `b`.

For example, consider:

```
ClassA a1 = new ClassA();
ClassA a2 = new ClassA();

a1.a = 10;
a2.a = 20;
Console.WriteLine(a1.a);
```

It would be very weird for that to print 20 instead of 10.

This is allowed in Java, and I've seen it lead to loads of people getting confused by things like:

```
Thread t = new Thread(...);
t.start();
t.sleep(1000);
```

... which makes it *look* like you're making the new thread sleep, when actually `Thread.sleep` is a static method which makes the existing thread sleep.

I for one am very glad this *isn't* allowed in C#.

Comment: I checked, in c#, non-static method can call static method; in the static method, the static variable can be changed; that means C# protection is not as complete as we thought.

Comment: @AdamLee: What? I never suggested that a non-static method couldn't call a static method. It's just that you can't call a static method *as if it's an instance method* - that's the code that would be confusing. If an instance method wants to change static state, it can do - and sometimes that's appropriate (e.g. updating a cache). But it's *not* appropriate to call a static method via a variable, e.g. `foo.SomeMethod()`.

Comment: I agreed, Jon. I just mean in C#, instance can still have ways to modify static variables in a simple way.(by calling instance method). I just want to point out C#'s protection is very weak, actually.

Comment: While I get the Java argument a bit (although I have never experienced it in 10 years of Java development), I think a) this has more to do with poor API design, and b) there is a counter argument here. In Java it is good practice to make pure functions static. Forcing static methods to be always called statically exposes this very technical, internal implementation detail to the caller. Also, switching around between static and method invocations looks really ugly, so we just don't do that in C#. At least we have extension methods that solve some of these cases, but require their own class.

Comment: @OliverSchimmer: I don't buy the argument that Java and C# are particularly different in that respect. The fact that a method is static is far from an implementation detail. It's an integral part of the API. It's really not that ugly to call a static method, in either C# or Java. I still believe this was just a bad bit of language design.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks, I really appreciate your work! Now, to the point. I don't like tight coupling to a concrete type, when it isn't really necessary. For the same reason we don't write `new` everywhere anymore. Now, for API stuff like `MyContainer.Load(repository)` static invocation is the only reasonable thing. But if you have an object with assoiciated methods of which 3 are pure and 2 aren't (because let's say, they require context), it just looks weird having to call them differently. And it would be a bigger hassle for example promoting them to an interface (i.e. making them non-static).

Comment: @JonSkeet But I do get you. I think the fundamental problem is that any `pure` function could be `static`, but `static` does not imply pure. The caller cannot know whether the `static` is important. The problem with `Thread.sleep` I think is more it having side effects on something else, you don't provide as an argument. I do however think being pure can be an implementation detail, especially considering that many pure functions in C# aren't static for this reason here. In Java I think of `static` as a safety lock for the next dev: 'hey, before you introduce state here, consider that'.

Comment: @OliverSchimmer: It's certainly not an implementation detail in that changing it is a massively breaking change, and it changes how it's called. The problem with `Thread.sleep` is *not* around side-effects, it's around the implication that if you call it with `myThread.sleep` it *looks* like it's associated with `myThread`, but it's really not. It's plainly misleading code IMO.

Comment: @JonSkeet That's not what I said - I said being pure can be an implementation detail of a method. The only way to _not_ hide it, is to make the method static. And I'm not sure I buy the 'it looks like' argument. The whole point of extension methods is to make them look like something they're not (e.g. not static). Refactoring members to extension methods and back is also a breaking change, and APIs still do that. Not every ASP.NET Html-Extension is associated with, or _needs_ the Html Helper instance, for example.
Again, I do get your point.

Comment: @OliverSchimmer: You said "Forcing static methods to be always called statically exposes this very technical, internal implementation detail to the caller" - that sounds like you consider being static to be an implementation detail. And the point of extension methods is that they *do* operate on the "target" of the method... whereas `myThread.sleep` really doesn't. I don't think discussing this any further will be profitable though. I would be very, very surprised if you could convince me this wasn't just a design mistake in Java (and one I suspect the designers now regret).

Comment: @JonSkeet Yeah, I did say that, and tried to correct it afterwards. I do agree with you that being static isn't strictly an implementation detail. But making a non static method static isn't breaking in Java, which I found useful a couple of times. In practice I found that good APIs don't do to you, what `Thread.sleep` does - mixing state and logic. The .NET folks might have put it in a static class `Threads` (plural) to indicate that. Anyways, I think that's not the best example, because the Java API has so many design flaws, it's often hard to put the finger on one clear issue.

Comment: @JonSkeet From a design standpoint I can believe you. As Crockford says, being sometimes useful is not sufficient for something to be in a language.

Comment: Since in C++ a static member can be called by an instance, can I make a conclusion that there is no underlying logical contradiction in calling a static member by instance but just the language feature of C# to avoid confusion when people read code?

Comment: @NeNe: No, I don't think you can come to that conclusion. Something can be fundamentally illogical but still supported by a language.

Answer (score 0):

because static members are part of a class, but instance members are associated with instances, thats why when you access static members  you should access it through the name of the class, this is one of the reasons behind this.